# Get-SBNamespace truncates ManageUsers list when its long

Tags: servicebus

Get-SBNamespace

When I run this, and I have a list of ManageUsers, it truncates the list.

```
PS C:\Program Files\Service Bus\1.1> Get-SBNamespace


SubscriptionId        : 00000000000000000000000000000000
State                 : Active
Name                  : NameSpaceOne
AddressingScheme      : Path
CreatedTime           : 9/14/2017 8:39:34 PM
IssuerName            : NameSpaceOne
IssuerUri             : NameSpaceOne
ManageUsers           : {Me@mycompany.com,You@mycompany.com,Others@mycomp
DnsEntry              :
PrimarySymmetricKey   : No No No
SecondarySymmetricKey :

SubscriptionId        : 00000000000000000000000000000000
State                 : Active
Name                  : NameSpaceTwo
AddressingScheme      : Path
CreatedTime           : 2/14/2017 7:32:39 PM
IssuerName            : NameSpaceTwo
IssuerUri             : NameSpaceTwo
ManageUsers           : {Me@mycompany.com,You@mycompany.com,Others@mycomp
DnsEntry              :
PrimarySymmetricKey   : No No No
SecondarySymmetricKey :
```

Is there a way to get the ManagerUsers values, when there is many of them?

```
#stopTruncatingMe
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(Get-SBNamespace).ManageUsers
```

will access to the ManagerUsers property and display the full list of users.